# how to download partial view as a word document in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xceed, asp.net-mvc-views

I want to download a **partial view as a word document** in **asp.net mvc**.
I'm using **Xceed Words Library**. Here is my code.

```
public FileStreamResult Download()
  {
     DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Test.docx");

     //appending paragraph text
     Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();
     p.Append("I am ").Append("bold").Bold()

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    document.SaveAs(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;

    var file = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")

     {
     FileDownloadName = string.Format("test_{0}.docx", 
     DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"))
     };

     return file;
     }
```

instead of appending paragraph text, i want to append a partial view & generate a word document.

Comment: you just want to download the file, right? why should it be a partial view?

Comment: i want to download content inside a partial view. divs, paragraphs.etc...

Comment: am sorry...you want to see the content of docx file in the partial view?

Comment: you didn't get it. i want to export partial view content into word document. please re-read the questions.

Comment: it's a strange requirement...not sure why you want to dump html in word document...let me ask one more question...you want to build a partial view in this same controller method and then dump it into the word document, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.Action("Download", "YourController")` in your partial view.

Comment: can you elaborate it a little more. please?